# Gaussian surface in a charged infinite plance sheet

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

The following question arises on the use of Gauss law. In the charged finite sheet problem, we consider a Gaussian surface on only one side of the sheet. But, In the case of an infinite sheet, we consider two sides for Gaussian surface. Why? I couldn't catch this idea.

Comment: How do you use it in finite sheet problem. Plz. Tell.

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve a finite sheet using Gauss's law, as you don't know the direction of the field from symmetry.